# json from kafka cant convert to pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, apache-kafka

hey i have the code like this for consume kafka data

```
 bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092']
 topicName = 'testapp5'
 consumer = KafkaConsumer (topicName, group_id ='group1',bootstrap_servers = bootstrap_servers)
 for msg in consumer:
       print("Topic Name=%s,Message=%s"%(msg.topic,msg.value))
```

and then i want to load the data with

```
  message = json.loads(msg.value)
```

the output:

```
 {'request_id': 'f84c55fd-c730-49ba-83b2-47b04643b706',
'data': {'age': 24,
'workclass': 'Self-emp-not-inc',
'fnlwgt': 188274,
'education': 'Bachelors',
'marital_status': 'Never-married',
'occupation': 'Sales',
'relationship': 'Not-in-family',
'race': 'White',
'gender': 'Male',
'capital_gain': 0,
'capital_loss': 0,
'hours_per_week': 50,
'native_country': 'United-States',
'income_bracket': '<=50K.'}}
```

and then i want to change the data to pandas dataframe with

```
  row = pd.DataFrame(message, index=[0])
```

and the output:

[image: output]

what should i do to make json from kafka can access with pandas dataframe?
thanks before

Comment: Use `pd.json_normalize(message)`

Comment: Your dataframe would only be one row, so why use pandas?

Comment: what recommendations should be used? @OneCricketeer

Comment: You only need `json.loads` for a single message, as you've stated in the question, which you can pass as `value_deserializer` to the consumer. It's unclear to me why you'd want pandas when you don't have a batch of messages. If you did want a record batch and dataframes, then pyspark w/ structured streaming could accomplish that, otherwise you need to accumulate records into a list periodically, then flush that list into a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplest approach is to use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).  If you just want **data** you can use `pd.DataFrame` using dict key.

```
js = {'request_id': 'f84c55fd-c730-49ba-83b2-47b04643b706',
'data': {'age': 24,
'workclass': 'Self-emp-not-inc',
'fnlwgt': 188274,
'education': 'Bachelors',
'marital_status': 'Never-married',
'occupation': 'Sales',
'relationship': 'Not-in-family',
'race': 'White',
'gender': 'Male',
'capital_gain': 0,
'capital_loss': 0,
'hours_per_week': 50,
'native_country': 'United-States',
'income_bracket': '<=50K.'}} 
# simplest....
pd.json_normalize(js)
# if requestid is not needed
pd.DataFrame(js["data"], index=[0])
```